# How to convert txt file into 2d array of each char

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file I created, which looks like this:

> small.txt

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%eeeeeee%eeeee%eeeee%G%
%%%e%e%%%%%e%e%%%e%e%e%
%e%e%eeeeeee%eee%e%eee%
%e%e%e%e%%%e%%%e%e%%%e%
%eeeee%eee%eeeeeeeee%e%
%e%%%e%e%e%e%e%e%%%%%e%
%e%e%eee%e%e%eeeeeee%e%
%e%e%e%%%e%%%%%e%e%%%e%
%Pee%eeeeeeeee%e%eeeee%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I want to create a a 2D array `board[21][11]` in the specific situation.
I want each char to be in a cell, because I want to implement BFS and other algorithms to reach a specific path, it's a kind of Pacman game.

Here is my code:

```
f = open("small.txt", "r")


output_list = []
for rec in f:
    chars = rec.split()
    print chars     

inner_list = []
for each in chars:
    inner_list.append(each)
    output_list.append(inner_list)

print output_list
```

As you see the output i get now is `[[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%]]`

Comment: Your `chars` is the last line in the text file. You should put the for loop inside the first for loop `for rec in f`

Comment: What's wrong with `open("small.txt", "r").read().split()`? It'll give you array of lines and can be treated as 2d array.

Comment: You only create one inner_list based on the chars in the very last line. You need to move your second loop inside of the first loop. Just indent it. Also, `.split()` splits on whitespace. You want to `strip()` first to remove newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
with open('small.txt') as f:
    board = f.readlines()
```

The `file.readlines()` method will return a list of strings, which you can then use as a 2D array:

```
board[1][5]
>>> 'e'
```

Note, that with this approach, the newline characters (`'\n'`) will be put into each row at the last index. To get rid of them, you can use `str.rstrip`:

```
board = [row.rstrip('\n') for row in board]
```

Answer (score 1):

As another answer noted, the line strings are already indexable by integer, but if you really want a list of lists:

```
array = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

That removes the line endings and converts each string to a list.

Comment: This will also remove blank characters from the left side of the string. It might not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

- you try to split lines into lists of chars using `split`, but that will only split at spaces
- assuming your indentation is correct, you are only ever treating the last value of `chars` in your second loop
- that second loop just wraps each of the (not splitted) lines in `chars` (which due to the previous issue is only the last one) into a list

Instead, you can just convert `str` to `list`...

```
>>> list("abcde")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

... and put those into `output_list` directly. Also, don't forget to `strip` the `\n`:

```
f = open("small.txt", "r")
output_list = []
for rec in f:
    chars = list(rec.strip())
    output_list.append(chars)
```

Or using `with` for autoclosing and a list-comprehension:

```
with open("small.txt") as f:
    output_list = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

Note, however, that is you do not want to change the values in that grid, you do not have to convert to a list of lists of chars at all; a list of strings will work just as well.

```
    output_list = list(map(str.strip, f))
```